# Name wrong by one character on kuwait airways ticket

Tags: customs-and-immigration

My name is 'Gauti' instead of 'Gauri' on my ticket from Mumbai to London (layover at Kuwait). On contacting the airlines, they added an internal note acknowledging the error, but refused to amend the name. They said that boarding would not be an issue, but I am unsure if the immigration officer will take objection. Anyone experienced something like this before?
P.S. The flight is in october

Answer (score 3):

Immigration officer do not care so much about your ticket.

Airlines are often the major problem: the left hand do not know what the right hand is doing. on the other hand, I travelled a lot with some typos on the names (mostly on my companions: if you want that I book a flight, expect that I cannot type correctly ;-) ), and nobody complained.

So do not worry. Next time, try to check better (but I discover just half of the errors).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you contacted the customer care department and they confirmed that this is the way forward, you shouldn't be worried.

If this rassures you, just print out your email confirmation you received if any, so that you have handy just in case when in airport.

If contact was by phone, just drop them an email recapping your call along to the date/time when you contacted the customer support and what they confirmed to you and print it out.

Usually, the check-in agent permits boarding based on the earlier note. Such a method is generally acceptable for very minor name changes, up to 3 letters, Which is your case.

On the other hand,
Give it a try and log yourself into your reservation to manage online your ticket and check if you can update your name yourself up to 3 letters.

If you want to know why having same name as passport is important:

It's for 2 reasons:

1-  Transportation Security Administration (TSA) Secure Flight rules:
TSA requires matching passenger names against government watch lists.

2- Credit card (CC) fraud avoidance:
It is based on matching the passenger name to the CC cardholder name. Changing the passenger name after the reservation invalidates the record, and might expose the airline to chargeback liability.